# Unwanted message on IE, to upgrade older version

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I develop an internet site.
I want my site will be supported also by IE8 + IE9.

I get a message : 
**you are using an outdated version of internet explorer. for a faster safer browsing experience**.

I realized that on my code, there are several lines:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
    <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
        <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
    </a>
</div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

but I have IE9, so why is this code relevant (and is reachable for some unknown reason).

Thanks :

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - the linked question asks why the message pops up in IE7 + 8. This question is related to IE9.

Comment: Still I have problem on that issue - I have never found a solution.

Comment: Try this: Open up your site using IE9 and then press the F12 key. You should see a debugging window open. At the top there should be a menu with (File, Find, Disable, ...). Just to the right should be some text that says "Browser Mode: XXXX Document Mode: YYYY". What does it show you for XXXX and YYYY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my opinion IE less than 8 is worthless, so consider this issue as closed one.

Thanks, anyway :)